# How to select two columns from two different tables in relational algebra

Tags: database

I have a table named Suppliers(sid,sname,city).

I have another table named Parts(pid,pname,colour).

How do I select column sid,sname from suppliers table and pid,pname from parts table and create a new realtion which will have four columns: sid,sname,pid,pname?

I know how to use project but project can take only one table as input since its a unary operator.

Comment: “Relational” implies there is a relationship to leverage. These 2 entities don’t have anything in common. if you had an intersection table with sid and pid, then you could construct a query joining suppliers to parts.

Comment: I do have another table catalog(sid,pid,quantity). So can I join Suppliers with Catalog and the output of it join with Parts and than project(sid,pid).

Comment: Yes that’s what that table is for.

Comment: Got it. Thank You